# Keras Conv1D or Convolution1D

Tags: python, keras

I came across multiple implementations of a CNN in Keras and noticed that some people use Conv1D from from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D and others use Convolution1D from from keras.layers import Convolution1D. Is there a difference or an advantage to either one or are they possibly simply just different versions of Keras.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are just for different keras versions, before Keras 2.0 the layers were called ConvolutionalND for N = 1, 2, 3, and since Keras 2.0 they are just called ConvND.

Answer (score -4):

It's not about the versions. The n stands for the dimension of data, for e.g. if you are using a text data you use n=1 i.e. convolution1d. The value of n=2 is used for images. The value for n=3 goes for mri or ct scan. So, depending on the dimensions we use the value.